# Use Iteration number in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm loading data from Flat file into the SQL Server Database using SSIS.

While loading I have load to one column called "Iteration". The value of this column should increment for every 100 rows inserted. For eg.,

```
+----------------+-------+
| Columns        | Iter  |
+----------------+-------+
| First 100 rows | 0     |
+----------------+-------+
| Next 100 rows  | 1     |
+----------------+-------+
| Next 100 rows  | 2     |
+----------------+-------+
```

I have no idea how to do this as I'm new to SSIS. I tried using `counter` with a variable. But not working. Is this possible in SSIS?

Comment: Use an integer row number and minus 1 and then divide by 100? `{0 to 99} / 100 = 0`, `{100 to 199} / 100 = 1`, etc, etc

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. But I dont know how to create the row number in SSIS? Can we use `row_number()` there? or As a derived column with incremental counter?

Comment: You can either do this inside the package, or you can load it to a table and apply the Iteration in the database with an update statement. I recommend doing it the database way. The last question I looked at was a bunch of wasted time due to using script tasks in SSIS - don't do it

Comment: I'd second Nick's recommendation to update the table after loading. It's easy SQL to write, but the SSIS route would be challenging and lots slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Variable to your package called `IterationSize`, integer and initialize it to your 100. If the batch size changes, let's change it in a simple, obvious place.

A script Task, acting a Transformation is what you're looking for. We're going to configure the task so it has read access to an SSIS variable called IterationSize

[image: User::IterationSize variable is listed in the ReadOnlyVariables property]

and in the Inputs Outputs tab, we need to add a new column called `Iteration` to the Output 0 buffer's Output Columns collection. Default type of DT_I4 is fine

[image]

The code itself is tiny. We will create a member variable called currentRowNumber and initialize it to zero. As each row comes into the component, we'll increment by one. Before doing that, we'll assign a value to our new column which is divides the `currentRowNumber` by our SSIS variable `User::IterationSize`.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    int currentRowNumber;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        this.currentRowNumber = 0;
    }


    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        // integer division is free truncation. Not testing for iterationsize of zero
        Row.Iteration = this.currentRowNumber / Variables.IterationSize;
        this.currentRowNumber++;
    }

}
```

For testing, I created a file with a single column that was always the number zero and had 206 rows. I set the iteration size to 3 and put a data viewer into my data flow. You can see the first three rows are iteration 0, next three iteration 1, etc

[image]

### Biml it

Get the free [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress) add-in for Visual Studio and the following Biml should recreate my package exactly. Well, almost. Something happened to the actual code but I'll have to come back and fix it. + file a bug report

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <FlatFileConnection Name="Flat File Connection Manager" FilePath="C:\ssisdata\Input\so_61794511.txt" FileFormat="Flat File Connection Manager" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO_61794511" Language="None" ConstraintMode="LinearOnCompletion">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="IterationSize" DataType="Int32" IncludeInDebugDump="Include">7</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Ingest file">
                    <Transformations>
                        <FlatFileSource Name="FFS Data" LocaleId="None" RetainNulls="true" FileNameColumnName="" ConnectionName="Flat File Connection Manager" />
                        <ScriptComponentTransformation Name="SCR Segment data" ProjectCoreName="SC_c69eec20ae0540169ee55fafada9521b">
                            <ScriptComponentProjectReference ScriptComponentProjectName="SC_c69eec20ae0540169ee55fafada9521b" />
                        </ScriptComponentTransformation>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="Place holder" />
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="Flat File Connection Manager" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" RowDelimiter="">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="Data" Length="50" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="CRLF" MaximumWidth="50" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>
    <ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptComponentProject Name="SC_c69eec20ae0540169ee55fafada9521b" ProjectCoreName="SC_c69eec20ae0540169ee55fafada9521b">
            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                <Variable VariableName="IterationSize" DataType="Int32" Namespace="User" />
            </ReadOnlyVariables>
            <OutputBuffers>
                <OutputBuffer Name="Output 0">
                    <Columns>
                        <Column Name="Iteration" />
                    </Columns>
                </OutputBuffer>
            </OutputBuffers>
            <InputBuffer Name="Input 0" />
        </ScriptComponentProject>
    </ScriptProjects>
</Biml>
```